Indy TIdFTP TSL1.2 Error 534 Protection level C not allowed
I have an older Delphi project where in we use the TIdFTP client. I have been unable to get it to work there so I have started a side project where I can test the component. I am also running a FileZilla FTP server with the minimum TLS version set to 1.2. However when I try to run the List procedure in Delphi I get a response saying

534 Protection level C not allowed

FTP Server log showing the described issue:
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1    Command       AUTH TLS
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1    Response      234 Using authentication type TLS.
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1    Command       USER test
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1    Response      331 Please, specify the password.
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1    Command       PASS ***
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1    Response      230 Login successful.
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Command       FEAT
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Response      211-Features:
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Response      211 End
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Command       OPTS UTF8 ON
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Response      202 UTF8 mode is always enabled. No need to send this command
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Command       TYPE I
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Response      200 Type set to I
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Command       SYST
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Response      215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla.
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Command       TYPE I
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Response      200 Type set to I
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Command       PBSZ 0
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Response      200 PBSZ=0
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Command       PROT C
26-08-2024 08:32:54   FTP Session 5 127.0.0.1... Response      534 Protection level C not allowed
26-08-2024 08:32:59   FTP Server                 Status        Session 5 ended gracefully.

I have tried changing the settings but no luck.
Delphi Code:

IdFTP Settings:

IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL settings:

I have not used Delphi for very long and this is my first time posting here, so let me know if there is anything else you need.

Your server (rightfully) does not allow unencrypted file transfers.
So you need to change the DataPortProtection property from ftpdpsClear (PROT C) to ftpdpsPrivate (PROT P).
